# Syntax error when using read's output as variable

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash, but I had to write a simple script to archive things:

```
ARCHIVE_FOLDER=".archive/"
TO_ARCHIVE="folders.txt"
TO_IGNORE="ignore.txt"

mkdir -p $ARCHIVE_FOLDER

while read t_arc; do
    EXCLUDE_STRING=" "
    while read ig_l; do
        while read found_exc; do
            EXCLUDE_STRING="${EXCLUDE_STRING} --exclude ${found_exc}"
        done < find $t_arc -name $ig_l
    done < TO_IGNORE
    tar -czf "${ARCHVE_FOLDER}/${t_arc}.tar.gz"
done < TO_ARCHIVE
```

It looks quite simple, but I get syntax error when using variables which are defined in "while read" construction:

```
./archive.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `${t_arc}'
./archive.sh: line 12: `        done < find ${t_arc} -name ${ig_l}'
```

Apparently, I can't even print them:

```
while read t_arc; do
    EXCLUDE_STRING=" "
    printf "%s\n" $t_arc # prints noting
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are 3 `read`'s from that script, you will need to use a different `fd` for the 2 of them. Also add a shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol after `<` is simply a file name. If you want to use a process substitution, the syntax for that is

```
done < <(find ...)
```

Alternatively, you can run

```
find ... |
while read -r ...
```

(Probably also change your other `read` statements into `read -r` unless you specifically require the weird legacy POSIX behavior around backslashes in the input to `read`.)

Comment: That works, but isn't `<(find ...)` construction supposed to write things to file? Are we writing to non-existent file and then reading the same thing in your example?

Comment: "Write things to file?" No, that's not at all what it does. Try `cat < <(echo hello)` for a simple demonstration.

Comment: But if `<` revives a file name, and `<(find...)` is definitely not a file name (as well as `hello` string which echo returns in your example), how does it work?

Comment: It's called a process substitution. The syntax `<(command)` basically creates a temporary file handle (something like `/dev/fd/63`) and runs the background subprocess `command` with its standard output connected to this file handle.

Comment: These syntax extensions aren't always entirely logical because Bash (or often originally Ksh) had to preserve backwards compatibility to the classic Bourne shell when introducing syntax extensions. Thus they had to find places where the syntax didn't already mean something else. I'm personally not very fond of process substitutions, though they can definitely simplify processing sometimes.